# invalid UTF-8 code sequence

Tags: python, sql, utf-8, nuodb

I'm trying to do a simple connect using a NuoDB database -

```
import pynuodb
connection = pynuodb.connect("DB", "servername", "adminaccount", "password", options={'schema': 'schemaname'})
cursor = connection.cursor()
thedata = open('file.pdf', 'rb').read()
sql = "update table set column = (?) where id = 1"
cursor.execute(sql, (thedata,))
```

in trying to load it's generating the following error -

```
INVALID_UTF8:  invalid UTF-8 code sequence
```

UPDATE - I've tried using both a BLOB or BINARY and both generate the same error.  The documentation on the data types is found here -

http://doc.nuodb.com/display/doc/Binary+Data+Types

Comment: Is the column a `text` or `varchar` column? You can't store binary data (such as a PDF) in a text column.

Comment: @Thanatos - it's a BLOB column.  Reference the spec here - http://doc.nuodb.com/display/doc/Binary+Data+Types

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `pynuodb` library gives you a special type to encapsulate binary data, `pynuodb.Binary()`; wrap binary data in that object to ensure correct handling:

```
thedata = pynuodb.Binary(open('file.pdf', 'rb').read())
sql = "update table set column = (?) where id = 1"
cursor.execute(sql, (thedata,))
```

Without this wrapper, the driver tries to send the data to the server as text, which must be UTF-8 encoded.

Comment: That worked and gave no errors!  Would the export be the same just so I can confirm the import worked correctly.

Comment: @whoisearth: you only need to use the wrapper when you want to use binary data as a query parameter. `select column from table where id = 1'` should just work.